# Javascript static variable in jsp inner html

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to use a javascript static variable in some inner html to generated dynamic ids for html elements. One of my code goes like this.

```
arguments.callee.selectId = 0; 

var techDropDown = "<form:select type='catalogOwner' id='selectTech"+arguments.callee.selectId+"'" "path='resources[${status.index}].techName'><form:option value=''>--select--</form:option></form:select>";

arguments.callee.selectId++;
```

But my jsp page is throwing Unterminated <form:select tag when trying to access this code. What could be the problem here. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: um, "javascript static variable" I am not sure what that means and setting html to a JSP tag is not going to work since that has to take place on the server.

Comment: aruments.callee.selectId is a form of static variable that can be used in javascript.

Comment: My point is JavaScript does not have "static" variables. And setting a JSP tag with innerHTML is still not going to work. The browser has no clue what `<form:select` is and the server is trying to process it. Client uses `<select`

Comment: the drop downs are rendered as <select> in my client also. If javascript doesnt have statics, then what exactly is arguments.callee.selectId.

Comment: Browsers do not understand JSP code or taglibs. They understand only HTML.Using Javascript to dynamically modify the DOM, you'll need to use only HTML code. "<form:select" is a taglib of framework which will generate the HTML code in jsp. But since jsp is already processed and HTML rendered in browser,you can no longer use jsp taglibs to generate HTML

Comment: then how can i dynamically generate form elements. I am using spring framework...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add jsp tags dynamically using javascript. But you can add html dynamically because it is understood by browser.

JSP tags are compiled to valid HTML by a J2EE server/container before a browser renders it. In your case, the request has to go to a server/container to compile and get html. Which is what AJAX is.

Comment: Thank you John for giving me such a good insight. I will change my lane now.